# Time(0) giving syntax error in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, time, syntax

Hi I'm trying to create a new table and want to create a column with the following syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename(
dinnerTime TIME(0) NOT NULL
);
```

I'm being told that I have an error in the SQL syntax, but shouldn't this just give me time in the format `HH:MM:SS` since I'm putting `0` as the precision?

Comment: What is the sql engine? SQL Server/Oracle/ or what?

Comment: You can just put `TIME` instead.

Comment: Ah right, just saw that I was using something that wasn't suited to MySQL. Thanks for the help. Just to confirm, this will give me the HH:MM:SS format, right?

Comment: 'HH:MM:SS' format is correct.